# How to print only parts of a page?

Tags: css, filter, printing

I am trying to hide some divs before the user prints this giant form, then display the divs again afterward. Thus I want to ignore the rest of the page, and only print the form itself.

Sure I *could* open a separate page when the user clicks the print button. The only thing is that the form is really long and it would be quite tedious to do that.

Edit: My previous question did not actually reflect what I was looking for. So I changed it to the current one.

Also thanks to all that suggested window.onbeforeprint and window.onafterprint. That was relevant to my edited question.

Comment: Regarding your edit: does my answer not answer your question?  I think the best way is add a style to your divs and then use @media in your style sheet or a link to print stylesheet.

Comment: It does. But I cannot accept two answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IE supports `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint`, but what you really want is a print stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224078/how-to-print-only-parts-of-a-page#224084)

Answer (score 28):

### First, The Ok Way:

Take a look at window.onbeforeprint and window.onafterprint (the original question asked about how to do it programmatically I believe).

### Now, the Better Way:

A better way to do this is with a style that is specifically for printing.  In other words, your div might look like this:

```
<div class="someClass noPrint">My Info</div>
```

You would then have this in your stylesheet:

```
.someClass {font-family:arial;}
@media print {
    .noPrint { display: none; }
}
```

### Another Option

You could also put this in a separate stylesheet if you wanted so you don't have to mix styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Your screen stylesheet could have ".someClass" defined one way and then your print stylesheet could have it defined a completely different way.

Comment: This is the way we do it at my company. It works very well and we don't have to muck with JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, we set noPrint on all our header and footer sections as well as any menus that shouldn't print.

Comment: I prefer to create a separate stylesheet that handles all print-related style changes rather than add them to existing stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider creating a style sheet specifically for printing using [media="print"](http://www.alistapart.com/stories/goingtoprint/)

Answer (score 0):

You should really implement this as CSS media=print styles. The media attribute of link element can be used to select to which media a stylesheet is applied. Check [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/stories/goingtoprint/)