# Can I change page layout when using window.print()?

Tags: javascript

In our application we enable users to print pages. We do this by supplying a button which when click calls the window.print() function.
Some of the pages would look better if they were printed in landscape mode rather than portrait. Is there a way to control the page layout from JavaScript?

Update: Following the advice given here I looked for "css landscape" in google, and found the [following article](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5803) that showed ways of css-ly defining landscape:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a print stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

More info...

[How to print only parts of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224078/how-to-print-only-parts-of-a-page)

Edit: to coerce landscape orientation, apparently the standard is `size: landscape`, but I have no idea how well that's supported across browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the update. According to the article I linked to in my question, that's supported in FireFox and Opera, but not in IE

Answer (score 2):

Do it with CSS by including a print stylesheet thusly:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">@import url("/inc/web.print.css");</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is not so much about using CSS to define print styles, but to force the print as landscape rather than portrait?

CSS 2 defined 'size', but I don't think this is widly supported:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_ref_print.asp

CSS 3 has better print control, but again not widly supported.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is still not possible cross-browser.  For Internet Explorer, there is an [ActiveX control](http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/about.asp) that does it.

Otherwise your best bet might be to offer the option of a PDF version for printing.