# Is there a way to make my html page print horizontally by default?

Tags: html

I hit print by accident earlier and realised my page looked awful printed vertically when it came out of the printer. Is there a property I can set in the code to make it print horizontally by default?

Comment: Do you mean in landscape mode (as opposed to portrait)?

Comment: In which code, the HTML on the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change page layout when using window.print()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239232/can-i-change-page-layout-when-using-window-print)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `landscape` for the page size and `media="print"`:

```
<style type="text/css" >
@page
{
    size: landscape;
    margin: 2cm;
}
</style>
```

Doesn't work with IE6 but should work with IE7 and better or any other browser.

See [this article](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/32962).

Comment: Sweet, this will probably do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS you can do:

```
@page {
  size: landscape
}
```

But I'm not sure about browser support.

You could always make the design more fluid ;-)