# Use CSS to hide contents on print

Tags: css, printing

I’m looking for an easy way to hide everything except a certain div and its contents.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="menu">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
  </body>.
</html>
```

So, for example, if I want to print only `div.content`, I would do it like this:

```
.header, .menu, .footer {
  display: none;
}
```

And if the layout is complicated, it becomes messy. Is there an easier way to do this with CSS?

Comment: You can print only div you want by following the article!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it css3 way: using not pseudo class and direct ancestors (children)

```css
/* hide all children of body that are not #container */
body > *:not(#container) {
  display: none;
}
/* hide all children of #container that are not #content */
#container > *:not(#content) {
  display: none;
}
/* and so on, until you reach a div that you want to print */
#content > *:not(#print_me) {
  display: none;
}
```

This way you can eliminate everything except what you want to print even in very complex layouts. :not is very efficient here because it takes care about any future modifications of you html.

Comment: How does this apply to *printing* only?

Answer (score 38):

```
@media print {
.noPrint {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Now you need to apply the class `noPrint` to the elements you want to hide in printing.

---

It is good practice to use a style sheet specifically for printing, and and set it's media attribute to `print`.

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: Be sure to add the print section after all other style sections have been specified. That way print statements will override other styles at print time.

Comment: question said: `looking for an easy way to hide everything except a certain div`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the most flexible of all other answers and does not involve using JS or using some JS plugin to manually show-hide elements.

Answer (score 7):

Assign a separate CSS file that  defines the behaviour when printing a web page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

and then within that file just define:

```
.header, .menu, .footer { display: none; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use classes.

```
.classHide{display: none}
```

Depending on the language you are using, when if==true you can add a class to header, menu and footer.

So you won't need to use another css file.

Comment: How are you going to tell these to only hide when printing using anything but CSS?

Comment: My point is that you cannot use a server-side language to tell the styles only to apply when printing. This is because printing happens on the client side, so the server won't know anything.

Comment: How does this CSS style applies to *printing* only?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your HTML structure (and browsers you need to support, because IE6 won't support this), you could hide all top-level divs and just show the one/few you want to show:

```
body > div {
   display: none;
}

#content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: How does this apply to *printing* only?

Comment: @robertspierre By putting it into a print style sheet.

Comment: this is not specified in your answer