# How to hide text with CSS when printing a page

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

I would lilke to hide text on a page when the visitor prints.

The text resideds in a

```
<tr><td>Don't show me</td></tr>
```

It is not wrapped in a DIV ID, or Class... so I am wondering with CSS can you hide this portion of text... ?? Would you use CSS selectors?

Comment: Isn't that same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page

Answer (score 5):

Use the `@print` media type in your css to assign a specific styling (like `display: none`) to prints only.

Comment: Or, you can specify the media type as part of the link or style element. Thus: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />` or `<style type="text/css" media="print"> .no-print { display: none; } </style>`

Comment: Something like http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it if you can select it but based on just one line of html it´s impossible to say whether you can just select that table cell.

I think adding something like a `no_print` class is your safest bet.

Obviously in combination with a print-specific style-sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, simply add

```
    @media print {

   .dontPrint {
       display:none;
    }

    }
```

Then in the part you dont want to print add `class="dontPrint"`

So for you, you could just do the following

`<tr><td class="dontPrint">Don't show me</td></tr>`

Now that part won't print