# How can I print just an area inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a top navigation area, a side navigation area, a control button area and somewhere in the middle a DIV with an `id="content"` that contains content.

I would like to be able to print just the contents of that DIV. I realize I have many lines of code making my other areas invisible and resizing everything but is there some alternative? Is there some way I can just print the contents of the DIV?

Comment: What does "print" mean exactly?  Like with a printer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page

Comment: check this link: 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at using [Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) - specifically `@media print` - in your CSS to specify styling that only applies to printing.

This way, you can write a stylesheet that hides everything except your "area inside a DIV".

Answer (score 1):

Use a css print stylesheet putting display:none in the fields that you don't want to print.
Use the tag link like this:

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css"

OR
@media print {

```
BODY { font-size: 10pt }
```

}