# Print Page Command

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

i am using below `code` for the `print`-- but if printing the `full page`. what do I have to do to print the `limited area` of the page (below the print button area)?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
if (window.print) {
document.write('<form><input type=button name=print value="Print Page"onClick="window.print()"></form>');
}
</script>
```

The above script is working fine but for only the whole page.

Comment: You understand this is Javascript, not php, right?

Comment: Hide your print button (or other things you don't want in print) page using media css. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page

Comment: You can add a print CSS to hide the stuff you don't want to print.

Comment: You want javascript to print your area of the page ? Not possible

Comment: Yes.. how can this `script` could make an impact on just `table`, means how can i have `print` a table only from the above script ?

Comment: always use lowercase tag. use this `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Although @ShivanRaptor is right about doing lowercase tags note that when it is an HTML document (so not XHTML) it is actually case insensitive. But please just use lowercase tags :)

Comment: @PeeHaa did I? I didn't mean to. Thanks for fixing that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
@media print{
  /* in here hide all elements you dont want printed e.g.:
   * div#header{ display: none; }
   */
}
```

Comment: Oh I got it. Need to put the code in css and related Div. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, you can all the print function with javascript, but you need to define whats visible when printing the document in CSS (using the `media`) tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@media print` css where you will hide all elements on the page that you don't want to print. You can set them to display:none and they will not show on print page