# Get current field name in to change display option?

Tags: javascript, adobe

I've looked all afternoon to try and find this one. Basically, I want get the name of the current text field and change the display value to noPrint if the text field value is "--". I'm running this as a validation script in a PDF. Any help is much appreciated!

```
if(event.value == '--') 
{
    event.target.name.display = event.target.name.display.noPrint;
} else 
{
    event.target.name.display = event.target.name.display.visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of things a bit off.

`event.value` doesn't exist (you can check the available [event properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#Properties))

If you want to get the value of the element that triggered the event you can do:

```
var elemValue = event.target.value;
```

If you want to get the name for the same element you can do:

```
var elemName = event.target.name;
```

To hide the element from printing, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356123/1385896).

Comment: Thank you, Filipe. I used the var elemName snippet and that did the trick. However, I had to use event.value. I tried to post the working code but it looked odd in this comment section. But I did really want to thank you for your help. If I could up vote I would.

Comment: event.value does exits -> https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2Fevent_properties.htm