# mvc 3 print view or export first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing small web app that have list of workers and theirs work hours. So far everything was nice and easy but printing is new to me :). I have made simple view inside that view is my table which is dynamically populated.

I need basically to be able to print that table for each worker, and every worker should be separate table on separate page. So page 1 should be worker 1, page 2 worker 2 and so on. Can someone tell me what is the best way to archive this, some example or tutorial,cause i never did anything that needed to be printed so far in my short programming career :)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite sure I fully understand, but the problem is to achieve tables on seperate pages?

To hide unwanted elements when printing check this topic: [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

And to force new page beetwen workers you need to use another css attributes.
Check this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml or http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470341/CSS-and-Printing.htm

Comment: Ty for links :). This is first time i deal with print so problem is tables in separate pages and how really printing in mvc 3 works :). Didnt find usefull tutorial so far.

Comment: It doesnt matter if you are using MVC3 :) You want to print web page and to do this you have to get familiar with css and create a special one for printing (thank to this feature web sites looks diffrent in web browser window and print preview window).