# How to have multiple css print layouts on a single page application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, single-page-application, printing-web-page

I have a single page application, and I have different sections where I want to print out list of images each on it's own page.

I thought maybe to use iframe for this purpose, but I wanted to have an answer from someone experienced with this situation.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Comment: @rps sorry, their print doesn't work on their own site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries to direct CSS rules at print time as described in this answer: [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page).

You can then set different classes on some high level part object before printing to control which CSS rules apply and thus what gets printed in a given operation.

You can also have a whole stylesheet withe the media type set to print so it applies only when printing.

Or, depending upon the specific situation, you can open a new window, put the content to be printed in that new window and print that window.  Usually, it's better to avoid opening a new window if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [CSS Template Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-layout) in the works and there is a [Javascript implementation](http://code.google.com/p/css-template-layout/) while browsers catch up.

I've had fairly good results with it.