# Removing a “Print” button Before Rendering PDF from View - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

Refered from [Removing a "Print" button Before Rendering PDF from View - MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512693/removing-a-print-button-before-rendering-pdf-from-view-mvc3)

[image]

Can anyone please provide the controller part of this answer??

Thanks in advance..
Merin

Answer (score 0):

i dont think anyone can provide the controller but here is something that can help. You can install [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa)  for that purpose then create two actions like

```
public ActionResult Page(int id)
{

    var data =  //here you will get data from database by id
    return View(data);
}

public ActionResult PrintPage(int Id)
{
  return new ActionAsPdf(
                 "Page", 
                 new { id= Id}) 
                 { FileName = "Page.pdf" };
}
```

and also there will be view of name `Page` in which `data` will be populated when it will `return` the view of `action Page` it will be converted to `pdf`