# Print mode in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there such thing as a "print mode" in CSS? Basically, I want to make all the edit I want to make so that the print preview looks the way I want it to look without having to alter the website I want making changes to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Comment: You can add CSS styles that only show when printing using `@media print`. See the link above. While it describes a more specific application (specifically, hiding elements), the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@media print` or `@import 'someurl.css' print`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly if you use the print media type when you write your stylesheets, that should work.

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

In theory, you can write a whole CSS stylesheet for print and have it look completely different to the screen media type.