# How to hide content but still make it printable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have an element (`#print-content`) that I'm printing with this jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print

I don't want this element to show in the actual page, but I want it to show in the print version.

What CSS attribute can I use so it still shows up in the print version? Maybe `height:0` or `position absolute 0` ?"

Comment: Have you use append on this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You can use just media queries.

```
#print-content {
    display: none; /*** Remove from the body ***/
}

@media print {
    #print-content {
        display: block; /*** Show just in print ***/
    }
}
```

Comment: short and perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't use a specific CSS attribute to control whether an element is printed or not, but you can use CSS media queries instead:

```
@media screen {
    #print-content {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This will prevent the element from rendering when the page is being displayed on a screen, but when it is printed, it will process it normally according to the rest of your CSS rules.

---

If you want the opposite effect (hide in print, but show on screen), you can use this:

```
@media print {
    #print-content {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

---

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for more information on CSS @media queries.

---

FYI, it's bad practice to use `display: none;` to hide the content by default, then use `display: block;` to show it in a media query. This is based on the assumption that the element's display type is `block`, but it may very be anything else such as `inline`, `inline-block`, etc. It also uses two rules instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use CSS to hide the element in a way that does not interfere with the layout.

CSS:

```
#print-content {
    display: none;  //may need !important
}
```

The element and it's children should not display, child elements should still print. More about the display property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Another solution (by Andreas Grech in the below post) is to use a separate style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

[How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

In the print style sheet, the @media print {} would be used to define what should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.clone()` , `.attr()` , `window.open()` , `.outerHTML`

html

```
<pre id="print-content"> (<span class="light">highlighted</span> portion) </pre>
<div>abc 123</div>
<button id="save">Print</button>
```

css

```
.light {
    color:#0af;
}
#print-content {
    display:none;
}
```

js

```
$("#save").click(function () {
    var text = $("body").clone();
    text.find("#print-content").attr("style", "display:block");
    text.find("#save, script").remove();
    var styles = $("style")[0].outerHTML;
    var popup = window.open("", "popup");
    popup.document.body.innerHTML = text[0].outerHTML + styles;
    popup.focus();
    popup.print();
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qz2too0o/