# PRINT: How to hide element and include element to print

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

Element should be hidden in media screen while include it when user want to print the page.

I use this CSS code but not working.

```
@media screen {
    th .hide {
      display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
    th .hide {
        border: 1px solid #000; 
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
}
```

html is like this:

```
<table>   
    <tr>
        <th class="hide" > Office:    
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide some HTML ? Else you write ";" after padding. It's should be `@media print {
  th .hide {
    border:1px solid #000; 
    padding:0.5em;
    }
  }`

Comment: @Nimesh I believe you understood the problem the wrong way: OP wants to hide elements from screen but print them however.

Comment: its a typo. well post the html could

Comment: @pistou you're right, deleted the useless comment

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page) a similar post

The best practice is to use a style sheet specifically for printing, and and set its media attribute to print.

In it, show/hide the elements that you want to be printed on paper.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question. I want an element to be hidden in the screen but print it anyway. Else your answer is not to the point.