# Skip elements while printing an html5 css page, but also keep the structure unchanged

Tags: css, html, printing

I have a Bootstrap page and I want to print it in A4 size. I have few elements which I don't want to print from this page, I am using this solution to achieve this:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

[How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

However when I use this, my structure of the page changes. That means if I skip say a text element, then at printing, that space is taken by another element. It should not happen.

I want to print this web page on a certificate template of A4 size.

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`. This will preserve the space occupied by the elements while still hiding them. `display:none` essentially renders the page as if these elements did not exist at all.

```
@media print {
  .hideprint {visibility: hidden;}
}
```

Comment: that is it....thanks a lot  Aziz ...just a small change    @media print {
  .hideprint {visibility: hidden ;}
}

Answer (score 0):

Using @media print you can set the display, I guess you are using display "none" so the layout changes.

You could use opacity or visibility spite of display. opacity:0 or visibility:hidden will keep the layout untouched, while making the elements dissapear (visually).

Comment: yes , I used   visibility:hidden   .. thanks @miguel-svq