# icCube - How can I export the whole report to an image

Tags: iccube, export-to-image

I created a report that contain a Pichart, Histogram and  DatePicker, I want to export this report with those components.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

icCube has a print report, but there is nothing to export a full report to an image, it's a pdf.

You can use your browser and print to pdf as an option. You might want to play a bit with css and media to make parts of the page not visible on printing ( [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page) ).