# I want to use non-printing buttons at specific locations on an html document

Tags: button, hyperlink, hidden

I have a "print this page" button that works fine:

```
<a style="top:-40;left: 375;position:absolute;z-index:5000;">
<script>
document.write("<input type='button' " +
"onClick='window.print()' " +
"class='printbutton' " +
"value='Print This Page'/>");
</script>
</a>
```

It is exactly where I want it and it doesn't show on the print.

I have several navigation buttons that jump to other pages:

```
<button style="position:absolute;top:1050px;left:-105px;z-index:5000;"> 
<a href="file:///C:/Users/jack/L-161%20Project/Rebuild/book/L-161%20Cover.html" target= "blank">Home</button></a>
```

These work fine, but they do print.

How can i make them not-print like the print button? I have tried several variations on modifying the print button script, but have not found the right combination yet.

Suggestions certainly appreciated. Please be very specific because I am very early into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page).

Put this in your CSS file or add it to your style headers like you did with the "a" elements.

inside of a CSS document would look like this:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Using inline-styles within your current document would look like this:

```
<style>
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

then wrap your buttons in the no-print class.

```
<div-class="no-print">    
<button style="position:absolute;top:1050px;left:-105px;z-index:5000;"> 
<a href="file:///C:/Users/jack/L-161%20Project/Rebuild/book/L-161%20Cover.html" target= "blank">Home</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you xec86. What a nice and easy fix. I didn't want to add a div, so I put the class in  <button class="no-print" style.... That seems to work very well, too.

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped you please mark it as a verified answer.  It does help me build my reputation in the community.