# Is there a way I can hide a DIV when I am doing a print of my page with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to print my page without headings.

Is there a way I can:

- make the heading `<DIV id="heading">` not show when I am doing a print
- and make a `<DIV id="summary">` show only when doing a print?

Comment: Yep: [@media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Comment: Google printer (or print) style sheets

Comment: This topic has been thoroughly covered already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to hide/show them via @media blocks:

inside css:

```
@media print {
  #heading {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media screen {
  #summary{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media print { 
 #heading{
  display:none;
 }
 #summary{
  display:block;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

.heading{display:none;}

means setting the display property to none ..will hide the element

Comment: OP's looking to hide/show the div only when printing the page