# How can you prevent print() from printing URL's and Buttons in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I got bootstrap to prevent printing href links, but the btn class I am having a hard time with.  I would like to also do it with input buttons also. `input[class]`.

```
<style>
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
   a[class="btn"]:after {
   display: none !important;
  }
}
</style>

<p><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg col-md-12" value="Print List" onClick="print();"  /></p>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/356123/3585500) says to create a `.no-print` class with `display: none;` and put that in every element you don't want to appear.

Comment: If you make that an answer then I'll make it the correct one!  :)