# How to hide a row in a table when window.open() is called

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm modifying an older application which has a table with many rows including the following row. (first question asked on StackOverflow, so hoping it's clear)

```
<tr id="volumeAvailable" class="standardRow">
     <td align="right" colspan="2"><i>Volume Available for TPN/IL=</i></td>
     <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalFluidsLeftInfo" runat="server" style="border:None; text-align:left; color:blue; font-weight:bold;" Text="0" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="NumericTextbox" ToolTip="0" />
     </td>
</tr>
```

The app has a click event which prints all controls/values on the aspx page by calling cmdPrint_Click below. A new window is opened which contains the print dialog and print preview.

```
protected void cmdPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string _url = "'./TPNForm.aspx?ID=" + hOrderId.Value + "&type=print'";
            string _target = "'_blank'";
            string _script = "window.open(" + _url + "," + _target + "," + "'status=no, menubar=yes, toolbar=no,scrollbars=1, height=400px,width=600px');";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick", _script, true);
        }
        catch (Exception _ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(_ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

My goal is to remove the above row from the table for the print view. I've tried adding volumeAvailable.Visible = false to the server side code to hide before displaying but the row still displays in the print window.  I've also tried hiding the row by adding document.getElementById('volumeAvailable').style.display='none' but haven't been able to get this to work.

Can anybody assist on a possible way to exclude this row when calling window.open()?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page) to hide an element only when printing.  To hide just the one row, you can use an [ID selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp), like this:

```
@media print
{    
    #volumeAvailable
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I needed.