# Passing whole page through POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a HTML page that stored in PHP variable that I want to pass to another page.

It's a big page that includes a lot of text and HTML tags.

How can I pass this variable?

I tried this:

```
echo "
<form action=\"toPrint.php\" method=\"post\">
    <input  type=\"hidden\" value=\" {$output} \">
    <button class=\"btn btn-info\">go to print page</button>
</form>";
```

But obviously it didn't work.

(Because this vaiable includes alot of html tags, it simply printed the text. probably the quotation marks inside the text, mess this up)

The reason I want to do this is because I want to send the page to a special PHP page that will present a printed version of the page without all of the menus around.

Is there other way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work __how__?

Comment: Your question needs to be more elabarative

Comment: @AzeezKallayi - that would be _elaborate_

Comment: If you want to print things, use a print CSS and have the CSS hide unnecessary stuff

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page - make much more sense

Comment: @mplungjan I preffer to send it because I have "includes" and a lot of junk around.

Comment: So resubmit the page to itself and have a flag on the URL or such telling the PHP not to include all the stuff. Alternative is jsPDF

Comment: @mplungjan There is no way that pass this data via POST or something to another page?

Comment: Sure, but very very pointless. You would need to escape the HTML in the field

Comment: Have a look at htmlentities which you would need to pass HTML inside a form

Comment: @mplungjan - P-E-R-F-E-C-T - worked like magic!

Comment: If you want, you can answer this and I'll mark it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion is to hide what you do not want to print, as detailed in [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

My second suggestion is to load the same page with a print parameter and generate the PDF from the content

Alternatively use jsPDF to grab the rendered page and output it to PDF

Lastly I suggest using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to escape the HTML