# Can I use multiple targets with PrimeFaces p:printer?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to be able to isolate 2 places in my JSF page to send to the PrimeFaces Printer component. Unfortunately I can not find an example of how to do this anywhere including the PrimeFaces documentation. Surely this command is more flexible than just taking in one target?

Using PrimeFaces 6.2

I tried this:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Print in a PRINTER FREINDLY format">
     <p:printer target="area1" />
     <p:printer target="area2" />
</p:commandButton>
    
<p:outputPanel id="area1">
...
</p:outputPanel>
    
...bunch of code between these two output panels...

<p:outputPanel id="area2">
...
</p:outputPanel>
```

no error shows up however only the target that is put first shows up in the print page.

Doing this:

```html
<p:printer target="area1 area2" />
```

results in a error.

Can someone please advise on how I can have multiple targets for the printer command in PrimeFaces?

Comment: it might just be that you can't. The source IS open  and free to use to investigate

Comment: Yes @Kukeltje perhaps you are right about not currently being able to. If I have some time I will certainly investigate. In the mean while a colleague suggested I use CSS, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

add your areas in a form and use:

```html
<p:printer target=":form:printable" />
```

Comment: This will not help if you need a "bunch of code between these two output panels" not to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot "target" multiple components using the `p:printer` behavior. You can just use one single component. If there are certain section(s) within the component you don't want to be printable, just hide the sections(s) using CSS media queries.

Something like:

```css
@media print {
    cssSelectorToHide {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)
- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)