# How to print a page in Angular 4 with TS

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an web app while in some pages I need to make a printer to print the page but I have a side bar and the rest ist the page for a component, how it is possible to not print the sidebar only this component, I have used in TS this code.

```
print() {
window.print();
}
```

Html code starts from this one.

```
div class="container">
//Here I have all the HTML source

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Comment: @baao Are you kidding with me, if you think it is duplicate show me here the answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

first of all assign an id to that component,
then:

```
const printContent = document.getElementById("componentID");
const WindowPrt = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=900,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WindowPrt.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
WindowPrt.document.close();
WindowPrt.focus();
WindowPrt.print();
WindowPrt.close();
```

Comment: This is working but all the style its gone, how it is possible to add the styles and other things ?

Comment: include those styles in that component tag,using style attribute

Comment: You think in this WindowPrt ?

Comment: no in your html, the component that you want to print

Comment: I am not understanding this can you show me a little example and I am facing with a problem when I click to print and print or cance then nothing works I need to reload page than to works what can you suggest me for this ?

Comment: for css you make an external css file, and before `WindowPrt.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);` insert this : `WindowPrt.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCssFileName.css">');`

Comment: i implemented it from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jdavidzapatab/6sctvg2z/) , you can also learn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171924/discussion-between-mohd-tabish-baig-and-zhuniqia).

Comment: How can I print the data in a single page

Comment: @Mohd Tabish Baig-sir i received WindowPrt  null

Answer (score 15):

You can try this solution.

> html file

```
<div class="container" id="component1">
//Here I have all the HTML source

</div>

<div class="container" id="component2">
//Here I have all the HTML source

</div>

<button (click)="printComponent('component1')">Print</button>
```

> ts file

```
printComponent(cmpName) {
     let printContents = document.getElementById(cmpName).innerHTML;
     let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Comment: Your code it is working to print, but when I try to print or cancel then the whole page it is not working ?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem

Comment: The print function only works once, when I try to click again the click function is not triggered.

Comment: I have the same problem, and when i console.log it throws this error : core.js:7187 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

Comment: Not perfect but after this code I call: window.location.reload(); and the page is at least alive again

Comment: Hello, the code creates the page but the text inside the form is empty and also the whole page goes blank, has anyone experience and sort this issues?

Answer (score 11):

In the side bar component scss file or css file...you can hide it when you are printing using media queries:

```
@media print {
  :host {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Direct window print function in typescript We need to create a new function with print() and inside that print function write javascript print function as shown below

```
<div click("print()")class="container">
</div>
```

in Ts File

```
print() {
window.print();
}
```