# How to add printThis() element exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, printthis

is it possible to not print a div include in a printThis() element ?

example :

```
<div id="print-it">

<div>hello</div>

<div id="no-print-this">
<button>must be show on page but not print</button>
</div>

</div>

<button id="printMe">Print button</button>
```

AND JQUERY

```
$("#printMe").click(function () {
$('#print-it').printThis();
});
});
```

the div id "no-print-this" is ever show to print... is it possible to hide it on the print page with this jQuery printing plugin method ?

Can add $('#no-print-this').hide(); to the jquery click function but div "no-print-this" is not show again after closing print window browser...

The @media print method have no effect here. So i dont know if its possible with the prinThis jquery plugin.

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Comment: humm no :) @media print use css only and PrinThis() jquery

Comment: `@media print` is a CSS media query to manipulate elements when printing. You'll still use JavaScript to do the actual printing. You might use the [`importCSS`](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis#importcss) or [`loadCSS`](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis#loadcss) options of `printThis()` to load the media query CSS. See [Styling Printed Content](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/wiki/Styling-Printed-Content) for `printThis()`.

Comment: Many thanks Showdev ! you true. i'll post the solution with your tips (loadCSS). its ok :))

Comment: I am the printThis author and and @showdev is correct - using `@media print` is the preferred method to exclude elements. Additionally, you may want flesh out the `@media print` to ensure a good experience for users that use `control + p` bypassing printThis

Comment: Thanks @jason for this information and you're very useful plugin :) clap clap :)

Comment: @nickko you can also add the `@media print` to your base CSS and you won't need `loadCSS` for exclusively print media (unless you are making printThis specifix changes beyond `control + p`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so the solution : (thanks to Showdev)

```
$("#printMe").click(function () {

$('#print-it').printThis({
            importCSS: true,
            importStyle: true,
            loadCSS: "/assets/css/print_rules_page1.css"
            });
});
```

it need to use inportCSS and loadCSS with the printThis() jquery plugin

**CSS** ("loadCSS" load file print_rules_page1.css)

```
@media print 
{
#no-print-this,#no-print-this2 *{
display: none !important;
}
}
```