# Open _blank with React component to be printed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to print a page in React? I have a suggestion to open a _blank page and print whatever's on that new page. However I would then like to render the elements that should be printed. How is it best possible to add elements to this new page?

Comment: Reason you can not just use CSS Print Media and avoid the new window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Comment: @epascarello yes, the reason is that I do not want to hide all the other stuff I have on that page