# Js print opens in only mobile mode, how to print in pc mode?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to print a table but the print dialog windondow shows only in mobile mode. How do I print on pc mode?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    @media print {
         *{visibility:hidden}
         .printarea,.printarea *{
            visibility:visible
         }
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        this content is not printable
    </div>
    <table class="printarea">
        <tr>
            <td>
                ... table content...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#" class="js-print-link" onclick="print()">Print</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION
Copied all the css media queries into the print query, my css looks like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .addr-table tr:nth-child(2) {
        border-top: none;
      }
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 683px) {
  .addr-table tr:hover:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: #d8e7f3;
    text-align: center;
  }
  }
   .........

  @media print {
    
    .addr-table tr:nth-child(2) {
      border-top: none;
      
      
    }
    .addr-table tr:hover:not(:first-child) {
      background-color: #d8e7f3;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  .....
```

Just copied all of them into print query, that does it!