# Hide a div in a page and make it visible only on print bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

There is a web page showing information to the user. If the user decides to print it I want to include additional information that is not required on the screen, but would be helpful when printed.

In order to implement this behaviour I was trying to make a div visible only for printing. It hasn't worked though:

```
<div class="row col-md-12 visible-print">
   some txt here
</div>
```

I think visible-print class work only on bootstrap 3 no 4
can you help me please

Comment: Less than 5 minutes after opening the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#display-in-print

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has great documentation and utilities..

Display in print

```
<div class="d-print-none">Screen Only (Hide on print only)</div>
<div class="d-none d-print-block">Print Only (Hide on screen only)</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-print-block">Hide up to large on screen, but always show on print</div>
```

more info [Display Print](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#display-in-print)

Comment: if the answer help you can accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following useful in BS4:

```
@media print {
  .hidden-print {display: none !important}
}
```

Now it is the opposite of what you are looking for so just reverse it.

```
@media not print {
    .print-only {display: none !important}
}
```

Comment: thank you , but I will use this one: d-none d-print-block . it's more sophistical