# Print FullCalendar Timeline Component Only

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, timeline, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar Timeline with the adaptivePlugin in **Vue**.
I want to be able to print the calendar with all the vertical data without the rest of the webpage components. A clean print of the calendar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide an element when printing a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page)

Comment: What you need is some media-specific CSS