# is there any other way for hiding an element on print then css

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, show-hide

I was trying my print code on different devices and on my phone the hidden elements still showed up after:
`document.getElementById("head").style.display = "none";`
and then:
`document.print();`
So my question is:
is there any way to hide it on phone or is there another print method.
I also tried `visibility: hidden;`.

Comment: you can have `@media print { }` stylesheet rules.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page?rq=1