# Printing button is also Printed during printing Document

Tags: javascript, css

I have created JS Code for Printing Single Id's . When ever i try to Print Document Print button is Also comes in Preview. i tried Every Possible Solution But nothing Is Worked

i tried

```
@media print {
  .noprint {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

But No Results

Here Is My js code

```
        function bookListPrintOnlyId(bookid) {
        
        var popupWin = window.open('', '', 'width=700,height=700');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        popupWin.document.write('<link href="{$resourcePath}assets/css/customprint.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        popupWin.document.write('</head><body ><div id="printabelDivOutput" class="printabelEquipmentsDivOutput"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive"><thead class="table-vertical-header" style="height: 56px;"><tr><th style="width: 130px;" class="text-center"><span class="header-cell">Equipment ID</span></th></tr></thead><tbody>');
        popupWin.document.write('<tr><td class="text-center">'+bookid+'</td></tr>');
        popupWin.document.write('<tr><td class="text-center"><button onclick="window.print()" class="noprint">Print</button></td></tr>');
        popupWin.document.write('</tbody></table></div></body></html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `display: none;` instead?  `visibility: hidden;` only _visually_ conceals it, and there are a few other nuanced differences from `display: none;` — see [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: Thank you for your Response. I tried but not working.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page

Comment: Tried Everything But Not Working. Css is not applied on Button

Comment: Just to clarify, did you actually try _printing_ it and the button shows up on print? `@media print` only targets the printed medium, which means it won't affect on-screen preview.

Comment: Yes, the Button Shows up on print